# Adjektivdeklination

Tags: adjective-ending, declension

I have already memorized the basic Adjektivdeklination but there are words that can work like an article like:

> jed(-), all(-), einig(-), manch(-), dies(-), jen(-), welch(-), solch(-), and etc.

These exceptions are starting to confuse me in situations where I ask myself which ending I should be using for the adjective accompanying these words. Do you guys have a comprehensive book/website/reference that contains what I'm talking about? Or if one of you guys has already noticed this and did write all about it, please share it with me.

Comment: Instead of *der* and *ein* you need to think about so-called *der*-words and *ein*-words. The *der*-words decline like *der* (of course) and adjectives behave as if following *der* itself when they follow a *der*-word. Similarly for *ein*-words. See the UW-Madison pages [here](https://courses.dcs.wisc.edu/wp/readinggerman/der-words/), [here](https://courses.dcs.wisc.edu/wp/readinggerman/ein-words-possessive-pronouns/) and [here](https://courses.dcs.wisc.edu/wp/readinggerman/adjective-endings/). In fact use the whole site as a reference for a lot of things.

Comment: You just saved me. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @RDBury: Why don't you write this as an answer?

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast  -- It's not really an answer is it? basically just some links to another website. Anyway, I thought that someone with more expertise would have given a complete answer by now. That's assuming that it hasn't already been answered in another question; this site gets a lot of questions on declining adjectives.

Comment: You can have a look at any pages explaining *der-Wörter* and *ein-Wörter*, like for instance these ones which explain very well: [1](https://www.coerll.utexas.edu/gg/gr/det_02.html) [2](https://www.coerll.utexas.edu/gg/gr/det_03.html)

Comment: Maybe this link can help you..
https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/adjektive/deklination

Comment: @RDBury: You could also create a  Wiki answer easing further additions (if you are afraid of incompleteness), but looking at the competition your answer may even be accepted as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Such so-called *der*-words or *ein*-words let the phrase decline in the same way as with "der" or "ein".<sup>([1](https://www.coerll.utexas.edu/gg/gr/det_02.html))([2](https://www.coerll.utexas.edu/gg/gr/det_03.html))</sup> For example (a few ones from the words in your question):

- der schöne Mann / jeder schöne Mann / welcher schöne Mann, ein schöner Mann / welch ein schöner Mann
- die schöne Frau / jede schöne Frau / solche schöne Frau, eine schöne Frau / solch eine schöne Frau
- das niedliche Kind / jedes niedliche Kind / manches niedliche Kind, ein schönes Kind / manch ein schönes Kind

You can see all following adjective suffixes are appropriatly equal. Look at how they end and imagine it behaves equally to *der|die|das* or *ein|eine|eines*, respectively.

Comment: once again transferred from the comment, but I hate it if questions remain unanswered.